# ngrx/store with ngModel caused some problems

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm using primeng editable table and ngrx/store. The table value is from store: `results`.

The parent component:

```
this.results$ = store.pipe(select(mySelectors.results));
```

use async to pass it to child componnet `[results]="results$|async"`.

In the child template:

```
<p-table [value]="results">
...
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
  <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
  ...
    <td pEditableColumn>
      <p-cellEditor>
        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
          <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.name">   // it's about this input
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
          {{rowData.name}}
        </ng-template>
      </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

the results model is like this:

```
{
 ...
 name: string;
 ...
}
```

I used `ngrx-store-freeze`. now the question is,the results from store cannot be changed directly. So even if I tried to use action to change values in the store, but I cannot get the changed value from the input tag with `[(ngModel)]="rowData.name"`, cause it's read only.

So how can I get the changed value from input tag, or is there a better way to do this? I understand that ngModel is sort of conflict with ngrx/store, and I tried to deep copy `results` then bind it to the table, but it's not working, the deep copy is still read only.

I'm stuck here. please help me

Comment: The biggst question I don't understand is: a value from store is read only, but why I still can't modify it after deep copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. There may be some bugs using ngrx-store-freeze with primeng editable table.
when out of p-table, all will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Ngrx store freeze prevent you to modify the state of the `rowData.names` because you are using input which mean you can modify the state.

So you can fix it by remove 2 way binding

```
<input pInputText type="text" [ngModel]="rowData.name">
```

Comment: yes, But I also need to modify the value from state by actions, and I can't even get the value if I modified the value in the input tag. Get the value and bind it to the input is the first step, and then I need type a new value in the input tag and update the new value to the store by action.

Comment: You should use Reactiveform to get the value not using 2 way binding in this case if you are using ngrx

Comment: That is the right way, but there are more problems using primeng editable table with reactive forms,I already tried that, it didn't work well, maybe I  didn't use it rightly, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ngModel to two way bind with data that comes from an observable you should clone it into a template variable before you start modifying it. Otherwise you are mutating the store data. I use a clone pipe

```
<ng-container *ngIf="results$ | async | clone as results">
  Do what you want with results as it wont mutate the store because it is a clone
</ng-container>
```

My clone pipe looks like

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'clone'
})
export class ClonePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return clone(value);
  }
}
```

and the clone function looks like

```
export const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
    ? new Date(obj.getTime())
    : obj && typeof obj === 'object'
    ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => {
        o[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
        return o;
      }, {})
    : obj;
```

It wont clone every JavaScript object but will be fine for anything that came from an API via JSON.

Comment: I tried, whether to use clonepipe or just deep copy the results from the store, it won't change the read only property, still can't modify it.

Comment: Then don't freeze it, no need to freeze something if you don't modify it.

Comment: Or modify the clone function to make a non frozen clone